# Advice on making first screen load super fast in React Native app

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

This is more of an advice question rather than a troubleshooting question. Speed is the focus here. I'm currently working in iOS but obviously planning to build for android.

I have built a React Native app where I am using the [react-native-nfc-manager](https://github.com/revtel/react-native-nfc-manager/issues) library. The function of the app is simple: read what is on an NFC tag and write to it (the NFC tag) in one tap. There are 3 screens:

1. The first screen (upon app open) is the NFC scanning screen and it is very simple- just a few components to activate the NFC scanner
2. NFC tag history screen
3. Account/settings screen

Screens 2&3 require API calls to some external (AWS) resources. No external API calls are needed for the first screen to be loaded or for the NFC scanner to be used. **I need to ensure that this first screen loads as fast as possible on app cold/warm/hot start.** My goal is to use RN for as much of this app as possible. As I see it, there are a few options:

- use RN to write screens 1,2,3
- use Swift/Obj-C to write screen 1, and RN to write 2&3
- go completely native.

I really want to be able to reuse my RN code for screens 2&3 at the very least - it doesn't matter how long it takes for those screens to load. I almost wonder if there is way to bundle screens 2&3 separately. I've done some searching/reading and can't seem to find exactly the information I'm looking for so I welcome links/reading materials that may help as well. Please try to compare any suggestions made to the performance of a fully native application, ie. "Option 1 will be just as fast as an application written entirely in Swift." Thank you.

Comment: Native will always be faster than loading the RN runtime.

Comment: Enable `Hermes` for faster bundling and quick start of RN app. For sure it will result you in faster start up.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes

Comment: @EmilioPelaez is it possible for screen 1 to be native and for screens 2&3 to require RN runtime to be loaded only when the user navigates to them?

Comment: Yes, It is also possible @EmilioPelaez

Comment: @Kailash so I can write screen 1 in swift to get the speed benefits of native and write screens 2&3 in RN, and the app will cold/warm/hot start as fast as native?